# order by for specific column

Tags: sql-server

I want to make order by ASC For specific column from more columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the ORDER BY clause in the SELECT clause, it must go at the end as the above code specifies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188385(v=SQL.90).aspx

You'd need to do this

```
ALTER Proc SelectAllCtageories_Front
AS
SELECT Parent.Id,
       Product.Product_Id,
       Product.Model,
       Product.Image,
FROM   Categories
ORDER BY Product.Model ASC
```

What's the larger problem?  Why are you needing to do this?  There may be a different way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add ASC when adding order by clause for the query.

eg. Select * from Customers Order by CustomerId ASC, CustomerName

Comment: Thanks But I want column  in stored as

ALTER       Proc SelectAllCtageories_Front

AS
Select  Parent.Id,Product.Product_Id,Order By (Product.Model),Product.Image,Categories.
Note With Sql2000